# update one column of a table t1 with the sum of values of another table ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

with ORACLE, how to update one column of a table t1 with the sum of values of a column of a table t2 with the following conditions:

table t1 (primary key = (ID1, ID2)):

```
    ID1 ID2  REFU
    a    x    0
    b    y    0
```

Table t2 (primary key = (ID1, ID2, ID3)):

```
    ID1  ID2  ID3  REFU_ID3
    a     x     m     2
    b     y     n     1
    a     x     o     4
    b     y     p     6
```

I want to update table t1 so that I get :

```
    ID1 ID2  REFU
    a    x    (2+4=6)
    b    y    (1+6=7)
```

NB : There are about 360 couples (a, x) to be updated

Comment: Shoudnt this be 2+4 and 1+6?

Comment: Yes sorry you are right

Comment: Rim .... umm Moroccan or egyptien  ?

Comment: i'm moroccan hit me up in chat if you want some help glad to help a sister :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
UPDATE t1 SET
       REFU = (SELECT SUM(REFU_ID3) FROM t2 WHERE t1.ID1=t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2=t2.ID2)
```

Comment: I was going to post this too, but I wanted to check it before posting. (plot twist - [it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7f37/1/1))

Comment: lol thanks for confirming lool i cant test it here we work mainly with mysql

Comment: Thank you very much I tested it and it is OK